# I can't get my XAMPP PHP mail() to work with my gmail account

Tags: php

I've tried to setup my XAMPP to send and receive my mails on a certain gmail account for a few hours now.

Mainly I've been following the tips from the first answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost) thread.

I've set up all the options according to the tutorial, but I can still see no mails coming into my gmail account when I try to send them to the account I listed in my .inis via PHP mail().

Note that I'm using all 4 parameters - Some tutorials state that leaving the fourth parameter will cause it to fail.

I checked my debug log and found this entry. Up to these lines, it all seems to work without any errors. It seems to connect to smtp.gmail.com:587, and then tries to authenticate as the account I entered. Following cryptic lines follow:

```
15.06.17 17:25:44 ** Authenticating as xxxxxxx@gmail.com
15.06.17 17:25:44 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
15.06.17 17:25:44 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
15.06.17 17:25:44 >> QUIT<EOL>
15.06.17 17:25:44 <<  5  1U‘oŒŒ;•¨&“-«†ÍÊŒegB‡¼¦©Ž( °Œ      ÿ   #  ÿ û ø z0‚v0‚^ EMZ\èÞé0
    *†H†÷
 0I10   UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G20
150218101956Z
151231000000Z0h10   UUS10U
California10U
Mountain View10U

Google Inc10Usmtp.gmail.com0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ Ö‡2Ž¦^š0ÔA“³ÊžVî®_æEZ©ä^ž-– Ülû+·&Pc°ñ{ ¯0*Úz
9­\¼"1W¡{OË1`å¾¼„/=£W\ôóûÉž…<4tç©²°#Ÿ1Wâãrºtß–ôxÊÒx&I—@P†sØßNBA…Ê   ïÔB
äø¾Nq‚#UÜßË§[}[·)   KÀlÔ‡…šhªžðÜz&lI³ÙàvF’{¸þŠyŽi   )ŒG;ö²
ðKCÓ0èw>›Mð —‡ŸŠ@Kæ£WÆ_l{L )šBóslb#Ô    +6Ö£ku@7Ô'lŒ80
Á £‚A0‚=0U%0++0U0‚smtp.gmail.com0h+\0Z0++0†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0++0†http://clients1.google.com/ocsp0U¡éh 8
åœ!¯C»øñe§Ú}0Uÿ0 0U#0€JÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0U 00
+Öy00U)0'0% # !†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ |ï´š­Óš›<R˜×™s%hDljHáæ‘ù)'Kì"F4{îë÷3ì9ãöÆŸ^©J    ©®iÀ–š€v>4ìwÃÀË<Ë³¼UghyÂ=ì°ñMì7³1ç§ÐïG‚ÖAbÚŠÍ¾Ì¼R9‹Ä¿Aùió;Ê«p3€ÎuÁ·ð;ÁŠPVyÑŸÓváK`†'!ºî2ø¦f«^…Ù>o#F† ÛÓB šò{rbõR„[Óªµµñ]ªåœ-,wY5#NÝpáˆ4bÇFyMÄ‚¾ñhAîD:è™ðf–O‡7EÃI7ÏUÁå»-¶D'íä¯Ø¯âà»K’Ì½ ô0‚ð0‚Ø :v0
    *†H†÷
 0B10   UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0
130405151555Z
161231235959Z0I10   UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G2
15.06.17 17:25:44 << 0‚"0<CR>   *†H†÷<CR> ‚ 0‚
‚ œ*w\ØP‘:£‚àØPH¼‰?ñpˆF~àÅñ‰Î!îZþa
·2D‰ tSOU¤Î‚b•îëY_Æá€Ä^”?¼[H8ôS÷$æû‘éÄÏôS
ôJüŸTÞ}¾ ko‡ÀÐP(0@ÚsQlÿ:<§7Ž½Kë}$Þæùü1qû”Õ`ó.J¯BÒËêÄj²ÌSÝK‹ÈaÍ¨>c+„5ie„ÈÅF"øS•¾ã€JÆ*ìº— Ç9™ ðaz•%ŒNRuâ¶íÊüÎ"j³NÏF——~À±Þ{¯E3Ïº>q·Þô%%Â
5‰ûy‰7Å¯Žri £ç0ä0U#0€Àz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0UJÝ¼öhµvõ¶»bºZ/0Uÿ0ÿ 0Uÿ05U.0,0* ( &†$http://g.symcb.com/crls/gtglobal.crl0.+"0 0+0†http://g.symcd.com0U 00
+Öy0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 'ŒÏéÇ;¾Àoè–„ûœ\]äwÛ‹2`›eØ…&µºŸÞdNÆÈ [    Ÿ«©à    4E¢e%7=Zo Ìùúñ:ÄÉv–¾›ùØ9ÑÅGv¸ŠŒ1Ö`ÕäÛú<ÆÕ˜(ø‘4ËËRzÑû: äá†±Ø¾Ö‡dÅ
%BQï²8¸àÐáüæô¯FºïÀ¿Å´õ”uþ¢¾ºê†[ù5³fõÅ…¡#wT`Ÿá´œ(*ù®4m%“œ‚¨{ñ…°ÓXáû±þœ¡£èýÉ?ô×qÜ½Œ¤à!##U¤    ~¹¯îÛSd½q/¹9Î0·´¼TàG 0‚}0‚æ »æ0
    *†H†÷
 0N10   UUS10U
Equifax1-0+U$Equifax Secure Certificate Authority0
020521040000Z
180821040000Z0B10   UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0‚"0
    *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ÚÌc0ýô#V~[ß<l8äq·x‘Ô¼¡ØLø¨C¶éM!ˆÚX/f9)½x‹8è·j~q¤æÄ`¦°ï€ä‰(ž%Öíƒó­¦‘Ç˜ÉB5­˜F’.OÊñ‡CÁ•W-Pï‰-€zW­òî_kÒ ¹ø5ÙÀF£{rÈ‘¿ÉU+ÍÐ—>œ&dÌßÎƒqÊNæÔÕ{©ÍUÞÈìÒ^8Så\OŒ-þP#6üfæËŽ¤9 ·•9‘þ8.ÑšöM>o¯,`9âú6S9Ô^&+Û=¨½2ë(Rqå«3=á8»6„bœyê0ô_À+èqkäù £ð0í0U#0€Hæhù+Ò²•×GØ# O3˜ŸÔ0UÀz˜h‰û«d}ª}e¸ÊÌN0Uÿ0ÿ0Uÿ0:U3010/
15.06.17 17:25:44 <<  - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/secureca.crl0NU G0E0CU  0;09+-https://www.geotrust.com/resources/repository0
    *†H†÷
  vánNK†0²ÏðÇÇq~fîÂíÔ;ÿððÈNÖC8°¹0}ÐUƒ¢jË6œèHf£m¸ÔGþ‹Z\sü®Ù28«—4ª–Òë£I¶»å‘ïƒ6ëVoÊÚ¼scä{>"Ë=í_8tœãPN¡¯˜îaò„?    
15.06.17 17:25:44 <<  F
15.06.17 17:25:44 ** Disconnected.
15.06.17 17:25:44 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
15.06.17 17:25:44 ** Disconnected.
15.06.17 17:25:44 ** Disconnected.
15.06.17 17:25:44 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

and then the disconnect follows up.

EDIT: The code I'm using right now to send the mail:

```
mail("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "Testmail", "Hello test", "From: Nils Reimers name@domain.de");
```

Has anyone got any idea what I have been doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: I added my code to the original post. Guess it's pretty standard. Note that the email I am actually sending does exist.

Comment: This is not a solution, but a suggestion. 1. gmail/hotmail has never been  a workable solution, they have filters and on different behavior it might trigger security alert and will luck sending/receiing email from 3rd part components. and it is a time killer for solve. Becuase you think it is your code but it is not. 2. Use mail gun or Mandrill

Answer (score 0):

You can try making subject a little more realistic as I have experienced "test' subjects gets blocked by mail filters as maytham suggested.
Are you using SSL, as port is 465 for SSL, not 587.

*PS: Sorry, I recently joined here, so cant add comments.*